# Question on Exact Sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, intuition, exact-sequence

I know that a finite sequence of module homomorphisms $f_i: A_i\to A_{i+1}$, is exact if and only if $$Image(f_i)= Kernel(f_{i+1})\quad i\in [0,\ldots ,n]$$

But if we have an exact sequence of the form $0\to A_0\to \ldots, A_{n+1}\to0$

Does that necessarily mean that the first half of $f_i$ are injective, while the second half is surjective?

In other words, does that necessarily mean $f_i$ is injective $\forall i\in[0,\ldots,\frac{n}{2}]$ and $f_i$ is surjective for $\forall i\in[\frac{n}{2},\ldots,n]$?

If so, then is this always the case with all exact sequences?

Anything you can say would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: Only $A_0\to A_1$ is injective with certainty. Similarly $A_n\to A_{n+1}$ is the only certainly surjective morphism. For example we could have
$$0\to\Bbb{Z}_2\to\Bbb{Z}_4\to\Bbb{Z}_4\to\cdots\to\Bbb{Z}_4\to\Bbb{Z}_2\to0$$ with an arbitrary number of $\Bbb{Z}_4$s in between. All the morphisms between $\Bbb{Z}_4$s being multiplication by two, hence neither surjective nor injective.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying! @JyrkiLahtonen so VERY loosely speaking, the size of modules is "non decreasing" in the first half, and "non increasing" in the second half?

Comment: In fact the only way that a segment $\cdots M\stackrel{f}\rightarrow N\stackrel{g}\rightarrow P\cdots$ of an exact sequence can have $g$ injective is that $f$ be the $0$-map.

Comment: No, There is no need for that. You can have
$$0\to A\to A\to0\to0\to0\cdots\to0\to B\to B\to0$$ with identity maps between the $A$s and $B$s, and an arbitrary number of $0$s in between.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much @JyrkiLahtonen and Andrea Mori

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for instance consider the following exact sequence of $A$-modules and homomorphisms
$$
0\rightarrow A\stackrel{f}\rightarrow A\times A\stackrel{g}\rightarrow A\times A 
\stackrel{h}\rightarrow A\times A\stackrel{k}\rightarrow A\rightarrow 0, 
$$
where $f(a)=(a,0)$, $g(a,b)=(0,b)$, $h(a,b)=(a,0)$ and $k(a,b)=b$.

(The sequence can be made arbitrarily long)

Comment: Thank you for providing me with another more general example! Much obliged :) I will accept this answer at the end of the day in case more people care to expand on this!